# convert model Codeigniter into MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

how to convert query codeigniter in mysql query

```html
function per_id($id)
 {
  
  $this->db->where('activity_detail_id',$id);
  $query=$this->db->get('t_trx_activity_detail');
  return $query->result();
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use Mysql query like this**

```
function per_id($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("select * from t_trx_activity_detail where activity_detail_id='".$id."'");
    return $query->result();        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can debug query using CI function.And get mysql query.

Check Query Helper Functions of CI [$this->db->last_query()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/helpers.html)

```
function per_id($id)
    {

        $this->db->where('activity_detail_id',$id);
        $query=$this->db->get('t_trx_activity_detail');
        echo $this->db->last_query();
        // return $query->result();
    }
```

Above I added one query helper function in your code

Answer (score 0):

A precise way to get exactly what Codeigniter does is to use

> get_compiled_select

for more information take a look [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::get_compiled_select)

In your Code - it would look like

```
function per_id($id)
{
    $this->db->where('activity_detail_id',$id);
    echo $this->db->get_compiled_select("t_trx_activity_detail");
}
```